# Scraping Flipkart webpage using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this page on Flipkart:

[http://www.flipkart.com/moto-x-play/p/itmeajtqp9sfxgsk?pid=MOBEAJTQRH4CCRYM&ref=L%3A7224647610489585789&srno=p_1&query=moto+x+play&otracker=from-search](http://www.flipkart.com/moto-x-play/p/itmeajtqp9sfxgsk?pid=MOBEAJTQRH4CCRYM&ref=L%3A7224647610489585789&srno=p_1&query=moto%20x%20play&otracker=from-search)

I am trying to find the div with class "fk-ui-ccarousel-supercontainer same-vreco-section reco-carousel-border-top sameHorizontalReco" but it returns empty result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.flipkart.com/moto-x-play/p/itmeajtqp9sfxgsk?pid=MOBEAJTQRH4CCRYM&ref=L%3A7224647610489585789&srno=p_1&query=moto%20x%20play&otracker=from-search"

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)

divs = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"fk-ui-ccarousel-supercontainer same-vreco-section reco-carousel-border-top sameHorizontalReco"})

print divs
```

divs is empty. I copied the class name using inspect element.

I found the answer in this question. http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22028775%2Ftried-python-beautifulsoup-and-phantom-js-still-cant-scrape-websites&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFOZIMVyUDcUqNNuv-05Dp7P_L6-g

Comment: try catching 1 class and then filter out your divs

Comment: are trying to catch, RECOMMENDATIONS BASED ON YOUR BROWSING HISTORY?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `requests.get(url)` you load the HTML content of the `url` **without** JavaScript enabled. Without JavaScript enabled, the section of the page called *'customers who viewed this product also viewed'* is never even rendered.

You can explore this behaviour by turning off JavaScript in your browser. If you scrape regularly, you might also want to download a JavaScript switcher plugin.

An alternative that you might want to look into is using a browser automation tool such as `selenium`.

Comment: What if I use urllib2.urlopen? I face the same issue with this.

Comment: That won't work either, unfortunately. I think your best bet is probably trying to use `selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get(..)` will return the content that is the plain HTTP GET on that url. all the Javascript rels that the page contains will not be downloaded, also, any inline javascript will not be executed either.

If flipkart uses js to modify the DOM after it is loaded in the browser, those changes will not reflect in the `page.contents` or `page.text` values.

you could try a different [parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) instead of the default parser in beautiful soup. I tried `html5lib` and it worked for a different website. maybe it will for you too. It will be slower than the default parser, but could be faster than selenium or other full fledged headless browsers.